# Strategy returns when increasing/decreasing a position

Tags: profit

When analyzing the performances of a strategy, the profits are computed as the final balance divided by the starting balance. What happens if the quote quantity has changed in between ?

For example, let's say that I want to trade crypto, on ETH/BTC. I start trading with 1 BTC on January 1st. On February 1st, I have 3 BTC : I realize that my strategy is good (+300%) and I decide to manually buy more BTC. I buy 10 BTC, so now my balance is 13 BTC and I continue to trade.

I could also give the example when the user withdraws BTC from the exchange.

How are the profit/loss updated for an arbitrary number of changes during the period ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to take into account the amount you fed in to your system, then compare it to the final amount of your system. In your case, your strategy profited 2 BTC. But you also bought 10BTC with $10X$ units of currency. So your profit should take this into account. Which would be $\frac{13-11}{11} \times 100$

But of course, there is the time value of money to consider, $$e^{-rT}$$.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear to me what you are asking, so I am hesitant to answer, but I believe what you are asking for is the internal rate of return.  If that is the case, you need to be careful because there can be one root for every change in cash flow direction.  So if you are in out in out in out, you will have more than one root.

You do have to standardize the unit of time, so you may also have cash flows with zero dollars.